# Align two images in the middle with text on the opposite sides

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to recreate the image below where two images are in the middle with text on opposite sides.

I've tried a few different things, flexbox, no flexbox, floating elements and haven't been able to get any of them to work.

[example of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMmiB.png)

This is what I'm working with so far:

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}

.inspiration-list-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 0 -16px;
}

.inspiration-list-container li {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 8px 16px;
}

.inspiration-list-container li a {
    display: flex;
    color: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    letter-spacing: inherit;
}

.inspiration-list-container li:nth-child(odd) .inspiration-description {
    margin-right: 8px;
    text-align: right;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: calc(50% - 8px);
}

.inspiration-list-container li .brand-logo {
    object-fit: contain;
    max-width: 64px;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-description .p-legal {
    font-family: Avenir Bold,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: .875rem;
    line-height: 32px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .p-copy-2 {
    line-height: 25px;
}

.inspiration-list-container li:nth-child(odd) .inspiration-image-container {
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-image-container {
    width: calc(50% - 8px);
    position: relative;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-image.placeholder {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-image.actual {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.inspiration-list-container li .inspiration-image {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<ul class="inspiration-list-container">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="inspiration-description">
        <p>Success Story</p>
        <p>placeholder</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inspiration-image-container">
        <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/inb32lme5009/4nojcxZUzehUfJ5JCGJpTQ/ab6b80302fa1c48d50c51b31d354517e/sephora_thumbnail_375x667.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <div class="inspiration-description">
        <p>Success Story</p>
        <p>placeholder</p>
      </div>
      <div class="inspiration-image-container">
        <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/inb32lme5009/4nojcxZUzehUfJ5JCGJpTQ/ab6b80302fa1c48d50c51b31d354517e/sephora_thumbnail_375x667.png">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Bootstrap and Flexbox currently in order to try and make it work but I'm completely stuck.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Center text]Try this :

html :

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div><div class="inspiration-description">
        <p>Success Story</p>
        <p>placeholder</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div><img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/inb32lme5009/4nojcxZUzehUfJ5JCGJpTQ/ab6b80302fa1c48d50c51b31d354517e/sephora_thumbnail_375x667.png"></div>
  <div><img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/inb32lme5009/4nojcxZUzehUfJ5JCGJpTQ/ab6b80302fa1c48d50c51b31d354517e/sephora_thumbnail_375x667.png"></div>  
  <div>
     <div class="inspiration-description">
        <p>Success Story</p>
        <p>placeholder</p>
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

css :

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  align-items:center;
}

.flex-container > div { 
  width: 400;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.flex-container > div > img{
  vertical-align:middle
}

.inspiration-description p {
    font-family: Avenir Bold,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: .875rem;
    display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1.5; 
   }
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/aviboy2006/6rqLax8v/19/

Comment: Thank you, it's much better. How would I vertically align the text next to the images?

Comment: you mean you need exactly center of image and next to images ?

Comment: text centered vertically next to the images. Like the screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMmiB.png

Comment: @bigRadBrad added new changes

Comment: thank you, do you have any advice on making this mobile responsive?

Comment: How you want to make responsive try this. Flex design support responsiveness